# Query to get all subtasks associated to stories with some labels in Jira

Tags: filter, jira, jml

I have user stories in Jira with some labels A,B,C for example. But at subtasks level there is no labeling. Now I need to fetch count of all user stories of that label, their tasks and subtasks.

How can I get subtasks which have no labels but linked to labelled user stories?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following JQL if you have scriptrunner;

```
( issue IN subtasksOf('type=Story and labels in (label1, label2)') or issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf('type=Story and labels in (label1, label2)')  ) and labels is EMPTY
```

It both finds the subtasks, and linked issues of the story labeled as label1 and label2. It also filters the issues with own labels.

Answer (score 0):

```
issuetype in (Task-Agile, Sub-task) AND issueFunction in subtasksOf("Issuetype = story")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.